# C# Inheritance with a generic type appears to be creating a different object type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have an abstract class that i use for entity framework. I then inherit the class and override when needed. In this case i have a post that i want to delete and with it i want to delete the comments associated with the post. The logic is simple, but i seem to be getting weird class type issues.

This is what i expected would work. However, `entity.ID` doesnt exist. In fact, 
 the entity object has no properties at all (in terms of visual studio intellisense). I tried to cast it and it says that it cant cast Post to MyProject.Models.Post, even though it should be the exact same class. So it seems that by using the generic type and casting it during the inheritance, it is making a new class of the same name.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractService<T>
{
    public virtual void Delete<T>(T entity)
    {
        this.context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }
}

public abstract class MyAbstractService :AbstractService<Post>
{
    public override void Delete<Post>(Post entity)
    {

        this.context.PostComments.RemoveRange(this.context.PostComments.Where(x => x.Post.ID == entity.ID));
        base.Delete(entity);
    }
}
```

I was able to get around this type issue by using the method below, but i dont understand why this happened in the first place. I am assuming there is a better way to handle this than the method of casting i have used here. If there is no alternative, what is making this happen in the first place?

```
public override void Delete<Post>(Post entity)
{
    MyProject.Models.Post pst = entity as MyProject.Models.Post;
    this.context.PostComments.RemoveRange(this.context.PostComments.Where(x => x.Post.ID == pst.ID));
    base.Delete(entity);
}
```

Based on the comments it would seem that something like this would be a more preferred way of implementing a delete, however I still feel the abstract method is of use as i have been using it for many other entities that do not have relationships.

```
public void Delete(Post entity)
{
    this.context.PostComments.RemoveRange(this.context.PostComments.Where(x => x.Post.ID == entity.ID));
    base.Delete(entity);
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare a generic type parameter `T` for the Delete method? Isn't the argument of the method of the type as specified by the class generic type parameter (also called `T`)? (EDIT: See answer below...)

Comment: It doesnt seem to like when i use a full namespace in the type bracket for the method call. i.e. Delete<MyProject.Models.Post> and it doesnt let me put it in front of the method param since it makes it a different type to what the generic was specified as

Comment: @DanHastings Indeed, you can't name the generic type that you're defining `MyProject.Models.Post`.  That's not a valid identifier for the new type that you're defining.  It also doesn't let you put that type as the argument of your method, because the abstract class that you're overriding states that the method parameter is of the generic type, not `MyProject.Models.Post`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Delete` method on `MyAbstractService` is defining a method that says that any `MyAbstractService` is able to delete any object of *any* type.

Thus when you inherit from that abstract class and provide an implementation of that method you need to provide a method that is able to delete any object of any type.  You've named your generic type `Post` in the implementation (you're able to call it whatever you want), but calling that generic parameter `Post` doesn't mean that the instances are of type `Post`, that's just the name of your generic type, so the object can be *of any type*.  If you want to treat the object as if it's of type `Post` you need to cast it, as you're doing.

Now you have a method that's signature *claims* it can accept an object of *any* type, but in reality it'll just fail if it's not an object of type `Post`.  That's bad design; your API is lying to its callers.

Instead it doesn't make sense for `MyAbstractService` types to have a method that can delete objects of *any* type.  `Delete` shouldn't be generic to begin with.  Instead it should just use the generic type *of the class*, rather than defining a *second* generic type (which you also call `T`, confusingly enough).

Comment: thanks for the answer. The first part makes sense, but im a bit confused by the last paragraph. VS does give a warning that the 2 params are named the same, but i get errors if i try to alter it. If i remove the generic type completely i get an error with this.context.Set<T> that T must be a reference type.  If i change it so that i use Delete<Y>(T entity) it says that it cannot convert T to Y. When both are named T it works. in all cases this method has worked, its just now with dependencies i need to make it custom

Comment: @DanHastings If `Set` says that you need to use a type that's a reference type then *ensure that the type you pass is a reference type*.  Creating additional types that you don't want is just causing you problems.  Again, you don't *want* your `Delete` method to be able to accept any object of any type.  You don't intend to provide that behavior, so don't define a method that claims to provide it.

Comment: I have updated the question with an updated example of the delete method. I see what you mean now with how i would need to implement custom functionality for the delete that is specific. The updated method works. However, i use the delete method from the abstract class for deleting many other entities that do not have relationships e.g. delete a comment. If my abstract method is still wrong, what should i do to correct it? I want it to be able to delete an entity of any type and this is what it is currently doing

Comment: @DanHastings No, you *don't* want to be able to delete any entity of any type.  It's not a sensible thing for every service to do.  There's not even a need to have more than one service if it's something that they *actually* can do.  And no, you *didn't* implement the change that I suggested in my answer.  Again, I said that the `Delete` method shouldn't be generic; that's the *only* change you should make to it; you shouldn't be also creating new methods.

Comment: then how should i do this? I understand that it is possible for me to have a comment service and use it to delete a post since its a generic method, but what other way could i write this stuff without needing to implement these basic methods in every service? Would it be better to drop the abstract and just directly instantiate the abstract class as a generic service?

Comment: @DanHastings As I said, right in the answer, the `Delete` method should use the generic type of *the class*, and not be a generic method.  That's the behavior you're actually trying to implement, so that's the behavior your abstract class should *claim* to implement.  Don't have it *claim* to implement some other behavior, only to not actually implement it.

Comment: it should be obvious that i dont understand what your initial answer meant, otherwise i would have done what you said. I was hoping for further clarification in the form of a code snippet that might clear thing up

Comment: Make the method not generic, add no new methods, and then you're done with the abstract class.  You now have a generic class with a non-generic method, and the only `T` that you can possibly use is the one from the generic class.  If I just write the code for you then you'll just continue to make the same mistakes going forward, and you're no better off.